# Why doesnt gdb step through LLVM IR Builder Call?

Tags: gdb, llvm, instructions

I was trying to debug a piece of LLVM code shown below. 
When I try running gdb on a call to IRBuilder::Create , it does not step in to the call and instead steps into a call to llvm::StringRef to create a temporary name for the instruction since I did not specify a name for the instruction.

How can I step inside the complete IRBuilder::CreateAlloca() call ?

( Reason : For some reason , one of the IRBuilder calls is not creating an instruction and I wish to see why , hence this debugging procedure )

```
 at ../src/utility_functions.h:1047
1047                        IRBuilder<> tempBuilder(allocaInst);
```

(gdb) n

```
1048                        allocaInst = tempBuilder.CreateAlloca(phiconstantType);
```

(gdb) step

llvm::Twine::Twine (this=0x7fffffffc590, Str=0x16cd8e6 "")
    at 
        /home/malhar/arm_work/llvm_versions/llvm_4.0.0/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/Twine.h:267

```
267       : RHSKind(EmptyKind) {
(gdb) n
268       if (Str[0] != '\0') {
(gdb) n
272         LHSKind = EmptyKind;
(gdb) n
274       assert(isValid() && "Invalid twine!");
(gdb) n
275     }
```

Comment: `finish` executing `StringRef` constructor and then `step` in again.

Comment: thanks , that seems to work , but I still dont see why the IRBuilder doesnt insert the call at the specified location ...